# Chrome extension REJECT when inline installation checked

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, inline

I made custom chrome extension which loads external javascript file (file is hosted on amazon s3) using XMLHttpRequest. Code snippet which calls this XMLHttpRequest is in separate file, and included in manifest.json under content_scripts:

```
   {
   "background": {
      "scripts": [ "background.js" ]
   },
   "content_scripts": [ {
      "js": [ "content.js" ],
      "matches": [ "http://*/*", "https://*/*" ]
   } ],
   "manifest_version": 2,
   "name": "Name",
   "short_name": "shortname",
   "update_url": "https://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx",
   "version": "1.0"
}
```

If I don't check inline install, it is accepted and published in few minutes.
But when I check inline install and choose site, review process takes a long time and extension becomes rejected. Domain is secured (https). And  tag containing info about extension is added to site's head tag.

```
<link rel="chrome-webstore-item" href="https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/itemID">
```

So, the rejection reason is probably related to inline installation method, and there should be some trick? Anyone for help? Is there something wrong I did?

Comment: So basically your extension executes an arbitrary js code that can be changed  at any time and cannot be controlled by webstore? No wonder it got rejected.

Comment: External file loaded with httprequest, is hosted on amazon s3 and it can be changed meanwhile of course. But as I said, if inline installation IS NOT CHECKED, extension becomes accepted and published in few moments, although there is "arbitrary js code".